# obfuscation in javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, obfuscation

im trying to obfuscate a string in vb.net and deobfuscate in javascript.

```
For i = 0 To Len(sData) / 4
    For j = 1 To 4
        ConvertData2 = ConvertData2 & Mid$(sData, (4 * i) + 5 - j, 1)
    Next j
Next i
```

the above said code works well in vb.net. I need the equivalent code in javascript

i tried the below one but not working.

```
for (i = 0; i<(sData.length)/4; i++)
{
    for (j = 1;j<4;j++)
        s=s+sData.substr((4 * i) + 5 - j,1)                  
}
```

anyone can suggest where i made mistake..

Comment: Can you supply an example string and it's obfuscated partner. Or a few examples maybe...

Comment: @user1547670 : How about initializing the variable s before the second for loop ? "s = 's' + ..." won't work if s is undefined right ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, Javascript string indices start at 0, not 1.   And your `for (j=1; j<4; j++)` loop will only count from 1 to 3 anyway; you want to go either from 0 to 3 (`j=0` and `j<4`) or 1 to 4 (`j=1` and `j<=4`).

A direct translation of the VB looks like this:

```
convertData2 = ''
for (var i=0; i < sData.length / 4; ++i) {
   for (var j=1; j <= 4; ++j) {
       convertData2 += sData.substr(4 * i + 4 - j, 1)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the first glaring difference is that in vb.net you use integer division while in javascript you are not...

use

```
for(var i = 0, len = Math.floor(sData.length / 4); i<=len; i++)
```

The second is that `Mid` starts counting from 1 while `subst` starts from 0

so use

```
s = s + sData.substr((4 * i) + 5 - j -1,1)
```

or simplified

```
s = s + sData.substr((4 * i) + 4 - j,1)
```

Lastly the loops, when using `<` do not use the final number ... while the `from.. to` uses the last number as well (*so use `<=`*)

so alltogether

```
var s = ''; // define s (if not yet defined) other wise use s = '' to make sure it starts empty..
for(var i = 0, len = Math.floor(sData.length / 4); i <= len; i++) {
   for (var j = 1 ; j <= 4; j++) {
       s = s + sData.substr( (4 * i) + 4 - j,1);
   }
}
```

Comment: @MarkReed did you try what you say ? I get `0,1,2` in the first case and `0,1` in the second.. (*and that is how it should be..*) Look at http://jsfiddle.net/n5ttE/ and the console output..

Comment: You're right, of course; 2 < 2.25 is true where 2 < 2 is false.  I withdraw my objection.